# Find which files are shared in iCloud Drive

Tags: icloud

This seems obvious, but can't figure it out. How can I find which files are shared to other people in iCloud drive? Finder shows individually a text under each shared file, but I would like to see a list of all shared files.

See more information about file share functionality (add people) on Apple [Support Pages](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph21250?locale=en_US#mmacef0ebabb) under *Share files* section where it says:

> You can allow people to view and edit files by sharing them using iCloud Drive.

If I share hundreds of files, after a while it will become hard to find and unshare files that no longer need to be shared. I'm questioning the auditability of the share functionality.

Comment: Does the iCloud Drive folder not work for you?

Comment: iCloud Drive folder works fine. I would like to find a list of files that are shared from iCloud Drive to other people using _Add People_ functionality. See details on Apple [Support Pages](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph21250?locale=en_US#mmacef0ebabb) under _Share Files_.

Answer (score 5):

I tested with this method in macOS 12.3.1 Monterey. This will list all sharing files.

This is modified from answer by @dvilchez [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388344/355318),
which no longer works in macOS 12.3.1 Monterey but the same principle works with modifications.

Let `file` be path to your file, `mdls "$file"` will show you all the metadata of this file.
If `file` is "Shared by Me", then we'll see `kMDItemIsShared = 1`.
(This is the key step to discover which metadata key to use,
which may not be in older macOS, and may change in newer macOS.)

Hence, **to search all files that is "Shared by Me", use**

```sh
mdfind -onlyin "$HOME/Library/Mobile Documents/" 'kMDItemIsShared == 1'
```

where `"$HOME/Library/Mobile Documents/"` is the root directory of your iCloud.

For any other folder,

1. right click the folder,
2. holding the `opt` key,
3. Click `Copy "..." as Pathname`,
4. run `mdfind -onlyin 'PASTE_YOUR_PATH_HERE' 'kMDItemIsShared == 1'`, remember to single quote your path as typically an iCloud path has spaces.

---

Original answer below:

Below is a non-robust and manual method to do this.
It has been working for me since the original answer on Dec 6, 2019.
I didn't document which macOS I was using, but from the date it is likely
macOS 10.15 Catalina or possibly macOS 10.14 Mojave.

Updated at Apr 14th, 2022 with macOS 12.3.1 Monterey.

1. Go to the iCloud Drive folder you want to find shared files,
2. search in this folder (by pressing `Cmd + F`),
3. make sure current directory is selected, not "This Mac", and
4. **search by `Shared by Me`** (quoted `"Shared by Me"` would not work).
5. Hopefully all documents "Shared by Me" is shown, per document,

   1. Confirm that it is "Shared by Me":

      - For older macOS version, only in the enclosing folder you will be able to see the file is marked as "Shared by Me". Right click and click `Show in Enclosing Folder` and check if the file is "Shared by Me".
      - For later macOS (e.g. 12.3.1 Monterey), you can see "Shared by Me" at the end of the filename.
   2. Remove sharing:

      - For older macOS version,

        1. right click on the "Shared by Me" file, `Share > Show People`,
        2. select `Share Options`, choose `Stop Sharing`.
      - for newer macOS version (e.g. 12.3.1 Monterey).,

        1. `Share > Manage Shared File`,
        2. `Stop Sharing`.

This method is not robust as you won't know if there's any false negative. And with macOS 12.3.1 Monterey I'm getting a lot of false positive.

Comment: @KLaalo, finally I've found the answer of this question. Please check and if it works for you, you can mark this as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how robust this method is, I have got some false positive (files that were previously shared), however it returns all the shared files.

```
mdfind -onlyin /Users/<user>/Library/Mobile\ Documents/ "kMDItemUserSharedSentTransport == 'Add People'"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. open a `Finder` window
2. in the menu bar (top of your screen), click `Finder, Preferences...`
3. click the `Sidebar` tab in `Finder Preferences` dialog/window
4. under the `Favorites` heading, tick the option box next to `iCloud Drive`

Comment: This only shows the iCloud Drive in Finder. I would like to find a list of files that were shared to other people from iCloud Drive. See _Share Files_ on Apple [Support pages](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph21250?locale=en_US#mmacef0ebabb) to find more information about sharing files from iCloud Drive.

Comment: Yes - I got that, but I didn't understand why someone would want to work from the web interface when the same functions are available in Finder. At any rate - all I think you're going to get from Finder or from the website `icloud.com` is a small shared notation (e.g. `Shared by me`) after the file name. Sorry this didn't help.

Comment: Oh, didn't actually note that the support page was for icloud.com. The medium is irrelevant. I'm interested about a list of shared files so that I can check that shares are current and necessary. If I share hundreds of files, after a while it will become hard to find and unshare files that no longer need to be shared. I'm questioning the auditability of the share functionality. It surely seems that there is no other way than to just check file by file.

Comment: @KLaalo: I agree that it's not a manageable situation for those who share many files, but it seems that's all that Apple offers :(  A cursory search on Google didn't reveal any 3rd party apps that support that either. You might try posting your question to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the files that have been shared by going to an iOS device (iPhone, iPad) and using the Files app or within Pages, Number, Keynote when opening a file. This functionality has been available for a long time in iOS but unfortunately it has not found its way  fo mac osx.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has provided this feature in latest update to Monterey. You now have *Shared* folder under iCloud in Finder. Similar functionality is also added in Files application in IOS.